# "Sorry, there was a problem checking our GitHub service. Please try again in a few moments."

Tags: github, synchronization, overleaf

> Long story short: Overleaf keeps returning: `"Sorry, there was a problem checking our GitHub service. Please try again in a few moments."` when I `"Pull GitHub changes to Overleaf"`.

> In details: I have used git to control versions of coding line on my laptop. These lines of code are stored in private mode on GitHub. Then, I have pulled these codes to my Overleaf account (I have Premium account with Overleaf), i.e. in Overleaf: `Menu` --> `GitHub` --> `"Pull GitHub changes to Overleaf"`.
> This way has been working well until I came across this error very recently: `Sorry, there was a problem checking our GitHub service. Please try again in a few moments.`

I have tried following the given instruction many times, e.g. by waiting and retrying after every hour and repeat the same thing on the next days. This error, however, still keeps showing up. Besides, I have also checked internet connection, just in case, both at home and at University. But both are still okay and there is no problem with internet signal. I am not very sure anymore what I should do next. Perhaps do you have any idea?

Comment: I'd suggest getting in touch with Overleaf support. You can contact them here: https://www.overleaf.com/contact. This could be a transient issue, it could also be due to a problem with the repo or project - Overleaf support can check the logs and likely identify the source of the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the hints @DanMacKinnon. OK, I have contacted [overleaf.com/contact](http://overleaf.com/contact) as you suggested. As soon as I have feedback from them, I will update it here.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you have any feedback from them?