# Updating overleaf project using git

Tags: git, overleaf

I have an overleaf project that I am working on. I have cloned it to my local computer using `git clone`. To this, I have added few image files to be used in the project and I want to upload it back to the overleaf server. I have done the following -

```
git stage -A
git commit -m '3 new images'
git push
```

This give the error

```
...
Writing objects: 100% (114/114), 45.27 MiB | 2.85 MiB/s, done.
Total 114 (delta 91), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (91/91)
remote: error: internal error
remote:
remote: hint: There was an internal error with the Git server.
remote: hint: Please contact Overleaf.
To https://git.overleaf.com/614f7fdc1d026c7c766f3612
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (internal error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.overleaf.com/614f7fdc1d026c7c766f3612'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75141174/sorry-there-was-a-problem-checking-our-github-service-please-try-again-in-a-f

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Although you might think there would be a connection, the git-bridge feature that this person is using is not at all related to GitHub synchronization feature mentioned in that other question.

Comment: Take a look at the troubleshooting and known limitations section of this page: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub, and get in touch with Overleaf support if you don't see something that applies here. It's possible to run into file size and count limitations when pushing: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_is_the_maximum_compilation_time%2C_file_number_and_project_size_allowed_on_free_vs_paid_plans%3F

Comment: @DanMacKinnon Thanks for the clarification! Then just a coincidence that there were two questions about git/overleaf today :)

Comment: @DanMacKinnon I think you might be right about the size limitations. The total repository comes to be ~2 GB. I did contact the overleaf team. Hopefully I will get a workaround for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue with the help of [Dan MacKinnon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75151138/updating-overleaf-project-using-git?noredirect=1#comment132617174_75151138).

There are size [limitations](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_is_the_maximum_compilation_time%2C_file_number_and_project_size_allowed_on_free_vs_paid_plans%3F) on using Git with Overleaf. If the file size limitations are not violated, it is the compiling time. The work around for compiling time is to reduce the number of changes in each commit.